# How to change the NSNumber value of the NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I trying to change a NSNumber value in NSMutableArray. 
How to do that?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSMutableArray *_numArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [_numArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [_numArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [_numArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];


    for (NSNumber *_numObject in _numArray) {
        // How to change all NSNumber Object from YES to NO?
        _numObject = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]; // <== Is this correct?
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can't mutate an array while using fast enumeration on it.

Comment: @NobodyNada The array isn't being mutated with that code.

Comment: @rmaddy Correct, but when he does mutate it he can't use fast enumeration.

Comment: @NobodyNada Correct. You can't mutate a collection while it is being fast iterated.

Comment: NSNumber is immutable, meaning that you must REPLACE the NSNumber with a new one if you want to change the value in the array.  It's not sufficient to simply update the pointer, since that's just a temporary value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in your question won't change anything except the value of the loop variable.

You need to replace the value in the array like this:

```
[_numArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@NO];
```

Or if you want to replace all, then do:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < _numArray.count; i++) {
    [_numArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@NO];
}
```

Comment: Hi, rmaddy, should there be double quotes around NO here?

Comment: @Unheilig no there should not.

Comment: Right, totally forgot about that.